# "予備あるしさ" What does this phrase mean? I was reading the manga and I didn't understand

Tags: translation

[image]

If you can help me with this translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it means, that she has some extra knitting material.  And now she is searching for it in her bag, so that he can try  to knit as well. 予備 means reserve, spare.